# Is this Pythonic? Assigning class methods dynamically

Tags: python, coding-style

Depending on the input to a class, different methods need to be used under a common interface (called `method` here).  Which of these is more Pythonic?

Attempt #1

```
class ExampleClass(object):
   def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
       if a is not None:
           self.method = self._a_method
       else:
           self.method = self._b_method

   def method(self):
       raise NotImplementedError

   def _method_a(self):
       return "I am a method that relies on input: " + self.a

   def _method_b(self):
       return "I am a method that relies on input: " + self.b
```

Or Attempt #2:

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def method(self):
        if self.a is not None:
           return self._method_a(self)
        else:
           return self._method_b(self)

   def _method_a(self):
       return "I am a method that relies on input: " + self.a

   def _method_b(self):
       return "I am a method that relies on input: " + self.b
```

It probably doesn't matter too much in this case, but in my case I have more than one `method`, meaning approach #2 violates the DRY principle (there will be the same if, else logic in each of the various `method`s).

On the other hand, is it awkward to assign the `_method_*` functions dynamically in `__init__` as it is down in Attempt #1?

Comment: If this is working code post it in [codereview.se]. On Stack Overflow your question is too opinion-based (unless Guido happens to answer it )

Comment: Both options run perfectly well and do the same thing.  I'm wondering if there is a "one correct way" (or preferred way) to do this.

Comment: I would definitely prefer the second option.

Comment: If methods a and b are so different that this is necessary, does it even make sense to pretend they're the same method? Shouldn't you actually have two different (sub)classes? With such a trivial example, how can we tell?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because `ExampleClass` is exposed to users.  It needs to keep its interface consistent.  Note the edit, I changed the class names of the two options.

Comment: I understand that you want a consistent interface, but that doesn't necessarily mean writing a single class. Also what if the user provides both a and b, or neither? Without more information this can only be answered with opinion and is really an http://xyproblem.info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that both approaches show bad OOP design and I believe should be avoided unless your whole `ExampleClass` API (including constructor) is already exposed to customers and should be preserved as is for backward compatibility. If this is not the case, I think some variation of [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) should be used, probably something like "static factory methods" as described at http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883. With such approach you can easily create objects of different sub-types depending on parameters. Moreover you can provide different factory methods with different names that better reflect meaning of created objects instead of just analyzing parameteres.

If your API should be preserved and performance is not critically important (and given you use Python, I take it for granted), I'd vote for making `ExampleClass` a wrapper that just delegates all the real work to inner delegate that is created via factory. Something like this:

```py
class ExampleClass(object):
   def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
       if a is not None:
           self._delegate = ExampleAImpl(a)
       else:
           self._delegate = ExampleBImpl(b)

   def method(self):
       return self._delegate.methodImpl()


class ExampleAImpl(object):
   def __init__(self, a):
       self.a = a

   def methodImpl(self):
       return "I am a method that relies on input: " + self.a

class ExampleBImpl(object):
   def __init__(self, b):
       self.b = b

   def methodImpl(self):
       return "I am a method that relies on input: " + self.b
```

Note: This approaches doesn't work well with inheritance from `ExampleClass`. Also if you need your `a` and `b` to still be public properties, it can be done but makes code much more convoluted.

Comment: thank you, this is a nice approach.  You don't mean `raise` in `def method(self):` do you? (return?)

Comment: @bill_e, yes this was a copy-paste. Fixed to `return`